# Losing WORLD position when importing to FBX (for unity)

Tags: unity, .fbx

i have made two animations, using the same base rig that play together, essentialy a judo throw, when i play it in Blender it works perfect, but when i play in unity (setting animation positions to original), both animations are played at the center of the bodies, instead of their respective positions. 
How can i fix this?

all other animations i had done work fine in unity, by putting into original position, they work the same as in blender, however i had to fix this one in particular due to a mistake i made, and since i dont want to re-import all other 90ish animations again, i made a new blender file and copied the mesh and rig, worked there, saved and exported.

i been trying to find a solution for hours, but it cant find it.

any help would be really appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

In the individual import setting for each animation on the FBX in Unity, there is a setting for applying root motion (location, rotation...).  What you likely will need to do is play with that setting some, likely by applying it to the root bone.  Without a file or other things to play with, I can't really go into more detail.

Comment: I think the problem is, the blender file itself doesnt have a root motion. and i dont know why. My other files do have it;|, im gonna upload a file in a bit with both the armatures and one of the animations :D

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6139" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6139/) Here it is!